# Modern applications and msvcrt linking

Tags: c++, windows, dll, msvcrt

As far as I can read on Microsoft docs, `msvcrt.dll` belongs to the past.

"modern" applications should be linked against new (understand better) crts (msvcrXXX.dll, vcruntimeXX)

Ok, but now, if I take a look closer at some "modern" apps (node.dll, chrome.exe, vscode, golang) I only see dependencies on... msvcrt.dll and that all !?

Comment: It is not exactly dead, it is now the *private* CRT that Windows executables themselves use.  It has been reverse-engineered by the MinGW project, they did not want to write their own CRT implementation and created the missing parts that are required to use that DLL, the #include files and the import library.  Pretty risky btw, fairly amazing that this never went drastically wrong yet.  But Microsoft in general has a high stake in not breaking existing programs in their next version.